# Can't find net.tcp endpoint in add service reference in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, net.tcp

I have common issue with WCF and net.tcp binding.
I saw all posts on stackoverflow also googling too..

The main problem that I can't add Service Reference to my client.
I get error:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
```

1. I'm using IIS 7. I checked non-HTTP.I added to web site in Enable Protocols net.tcp, also added net.tcp to bindings. If I click on browse(http) my address. I see my folder with WCF application, and if I select svc file I see normal address:

   svcutil.exe net.tcp://MYADDRESS/Service.svc/mex

I guess that I set my IIS correctly if I see this URL!!

But problem starts when I try to add reference to client. Only that I see http endpoints and no net.tcp.

That's my config on service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="MYSERVICE.SERVICE" behaviorConfiguration="behavior1">
            <endpoint 
                      binding="netTcpBinding"
                      contract="MYSERVICE.ISERVICE"> 
              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:60745/MYSERVICE/SERVICE/"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior1">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="netTcpBinding" scheme="net.tcp" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Note: my web site starts from 60745 address, but for net.tcp binding in IIS I added 60746:*
Also I opened Inbound Outbound rules for both ports.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have "Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation" turned on in your windows features on your IIS server?

Comment: If your program is .NET 4.5 do you have TCP Activation turned on in .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services (if your OS that is running IIS has it)

Comment: what'does it mean?
my services TCP activator and portsharing is working.

I can't find this  TCP Activation. And first time heard about it

Comment: I passed TCP activation.

Comment: I am out of ideas then, sorry :(

Comment: Scott
I found solution.
I should write my URL by hand because Add service reference can't find alone this endpoints. It can find HTTP but not net.tcp
Do you know why?

Comment: Scott write answer here, and I will mark it correct. You are one who tried to help me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the problem you mentioned in your comments, I have run it to that myself too the gui for Add Service Reference does not handle `mexTcpBinding` very well.

You can use HTTP mex for metadata and still use net.tcp for your data channel. Here is a example from one of my projects that is using tcp channels with http mex.

```xml
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpConfig" closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" transferMode="Streamed"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AsyncStreaming">
          <dispatcherSynchronization asynchronousSendEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="Example" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Server.Endpoints.ExampleEndpoint">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AsyncStreaming" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpConfig" contract="Server.IExample"/>
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AsyncStreaming" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpConfig" contract="Server.IExample2"/>
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AsyncStreaming" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpConfig" contract="Server.IExample3"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="netTcpBinding" scheme="net.tcp" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpConfig"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="false">
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
        maxMessagesToLog="3000"/>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
```